# Scrapy shell request doesn't match the response?

Tags: python, scrapy

The following is the code I run in the PyCharm terminal:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.puppis.com.ar/perros/alimentos/alimentos-secos#2"
```

Output:

```
Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x000001F4B3F77AF0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.puppis.com.ar/perros/alimentos/alimentos-secos#2>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.puppis.com.ar/perros/alimentos/alimentos-secos>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x000001F4B3F77160>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x1f4b4442d30>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

Why is the response output different from the request URL?

From my understanding the page with the "#2" gets redirected to the main page - without the "#2" at the end. Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Comment: #2 simply sends the browser automatically to that id, it doesn't change the response body (HTML will be the same with or without #)

Comment: #2 in this case refers to the second page of the website I'm trying to scrape, whereas the URL without the #2 is the first page. In other words - I was trying to scrape the second page but got redirected to the main page which has completely different results. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you should check the network requests XHR, there should be a request that is being made to get the data for the next page